# How to find out if a wordpress template file was accessed externally or internally via a custom loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

is there a way to find out, if a wordpress template file was accessed externally or through a wordpress function?

i have a onepager in development that consists of multiple singular pages that are assembled into one page via a central front-page.php.

i'd like to load additional stuff in the case that one of these singular pages gets accessed externally (i.e. not though my onepager template).

in my case the front page runs a custom loop that loads all items that exist in the main menu via

```
$template_part = get_post_meta($menu_item->object_id, '_wp_page_template', true);
include(locate_template($template_part));
```

each of these pages has a custom default template.

so if one of these pages gets accessed directly (i.e. not through my main onepager front-page.php) the page breaks. is there a way to know if the page/template was called through my custom loop or if the template was loaded directly by accessing the subpage externally?

many thanks for any possible help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. so if anyone else is searching for this: i solved the problem by setting and passing a variable from the front-page.php to the sub-template-parts, where i check the variable – if it is set, i assume that the template was called from the onepager. if not, i redirect to the main page. if there is a better solution to this i'd still like to know it!

ways to pass variables to a template can be found here: https://www.wpastronaut.com/blog/passing-data-to-wordpress-template-parts/